# Which part of the java compiler checks whether the public class name is same as file name?

Tags: java

Suppose we have a Java file with file name Hello.java, and in that file
we declared a public class with class name **HelloHi**. Now if we compile the java program with javac command we will get an error. Now what I want to know is that whether this error is done by the compiler in 
the classloader linking (which contains an activity called verification) phase.

Comment: *Now what I want to know is that whether this error is done by the compiler in the classloader linking (which contains an activity called verification) phase.* - The compiler (`javac`) doesn't do class loading / verification, so the answer to that part of your question is No.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unanswerable without reference to a specific Java compiler implementation, and without some hint as to what kind of an answer would satisfy you: a .java filename? a name of a functional unit?

The 'classloader linking (which contains an activity called verification) phase' is part of the JVM, not the compiler.